# Previewing unpublished drafts in Wagtail when frontend relies on headless wagtail API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, content-management-system, wagtail

Suppose I have the following setup:

1. A backend CMS in Wagtail which uses the Wagtail API to expose the data
2. A frontend that takes aforementioned API and using React, generates HTML & JS

This would break Wagtail's preview as it uses the templates by default. Unfortunately, the preview functionality is important to this particular project, so I need to find a mechanism to keep it.

So far I managed to create a template that outputs a custom-serialized JSON which is read by a specially built front-end.

Unfortunately, this solution is far from ideal as maintaining two serializers - `rest_framework` and Wagtail's endpoints (with `api_fields` on the models themselves).

I have not been able to generate JSON from Wagtail's `BaseEndpoint` (using `.as_view` or otherwise), but that could be a possible solution.

I've also considered generating an endpoint that serves temporary serialized JSONs for specific pages under unique timed GUIDs. This will technically expose unpublished drafts to the public if anyone gets that (temporary) link somehow, but that is a risk we might be able to take if there was a good way to do it.

How do I approach this problem? Have you solved it for your own project somehow?

Comment: You can use DRF serializer fields as custom serializers. `from rest_framework.fields import CharField` and then `APIField('test', serializer=CharField())`

Comment: Why are you trying to expose unpublished drafts? What's the use case?

Comment: @farooq Use case is that an editor would create a page and then would want to click "preview" to see a live preview. Since the frontend isn't implemented in a Django template but rather as a separate JSON-dependent FE it doesn't work out of the box

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview ? the README has a DRF-based example